# Identities involving the product of two commutators

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras

If I define the commutator $[X, Y] = XY - YX$, there are well known identities that allows one to decompose commutators involving sums and products of matrices into simpler commutators (for example: $[A + B, C] = [A, C] + [B, C]$, and $[AB, C] = A[B, C] + [A, C]B$.

However, there doesn't seem to be any reference that gives identities involving products of commutators. For example, I am interested in the following

- $[X, Y][Z, W] = \cdots$
- $[X, Y]^2 = \cdots$,

as well as the cases where one of more of the matrices in the commutator are (anti-)Hermitian. Is there a known way to write these products in such a way that only one commutator has to be evaluated?

Comment: I don't think there is a nice way to express these as a single commutator. You shouldn't expect there to be since such products aren't covered by the linearity of the commutator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general products of commutators will not be again expressible by only one commutator. An exception is, for example, the case $X,Y\in M_2(K)$, where we have
$$
[X,Y]^2=-\det([X,Y])I_2=\bigl({\rm tr}((XY)^2)-{\rm tr}(X^2Y^2)\bigr)I_2
$$
by Cayley-Hamilton.